# A bug in the contains() function of a Wall in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

all

I am using the Anylogic 8 to do some simulation but it seems that I found a bug there. Could u please help me verify it or solve it?

When judging whether a point is contained in the shape of a Wall, we can use `contains()` function provided by `Wall`. When your wall is `Rectangular Wall`, the function can return the boolean value correctly.
However, when u just create a wall and make it `Closed` in its properties, `contains()` cannot return the correct value.

You can just simply draw a rectangular wall and a normal wall (but should be closed), and choose a point `(x,y)` to test this function.

```java
// my code to test the contains() function
boolean flag=main.wall1.contains(155,5);
int flagInt = flag ? 1 : 0;
System.out.println(flagInt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the behaviour with AnyLogic 8.4.

It seems as if the contains() function is not differentiating between closed and unclosed `Wall` elements and only checks if the position is contained directly on the lines, not the enclosed area, even if the *closed* option is checked. For The type `Wall` internally the only difference between open and closed is the attribute `WallFillingType` is set to `WALL_FILL_HATCHING`. I am wondering that this is not implemented, as I know that the `contains()` function for `PolygonalNode` (which seems similar to a `Wall`) is taking the enclosed area into account and not only the lines itself.

In contrast, the class `RectangularWall` has a `contains()` function that takes into account the enclosed area, as you noted in your question already.

My only suggestion would be to write your own `contains()` function by retrieving the segments (`getSegment(index)`) and their coordinates, creating a [Java Polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) instance with the same coordinates and using the already existing `contains()` function of this `Polygon`.

Comment: Yes, that's a solution and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: By the way, even the 'contains()' function of `PolygonalNode` may have some problems. I draw some waiting areas for pedestrians and the areas are subclasses of `PolygonalNode`. I tested some points on the borders like (0,0) and found that not alll the points were judged correctly. I didn't save these examples but may supplement them later. I posted these issues here to remind the others to verify their simulation results when using these functions.

Comment: Oh, good to know! Thanks for sharing.... Maybe worth to notify AnyLogic support as well, seems like really unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I am a personal user and it seems harder for me to contact the technical support. Anyway, I will write them an email. My simulation involves helping pedestrians to schedule their walking routes and that is why I care about the obstacles so much.

Comment: Reach out to them via support@anylogic.com. Should be registered and answered regardless of your user status.

Comment: When you checked that the solution works for you could you please mark the answer as accepted?